# WCF HTTP GET parameter causes bad request

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service with the following operation contract:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/VerifyKeys.json/{customerKey}/{userKey}")]
    [return: MessageParameter(Name = "MyDetail")]
    MyDetail VerifyKeys(string customerKey, string userKey);
```

My method is like this:

```
    public MyDetail VerifyKeys(string customerKey, string userKey)
    {
         ...
         return _myDetail;
    }
```

My request is like this:

```
    http://mydomain.com/MyService.svc/web/VerifyKeys.json/FE3D0F1D-5B8B-4677-B332-70B7ABA80A97/08F4349A-30E5-457D-F2BD-70A23CE17F41?deviceId=66345ec6-a5fe-4b5f-8cf2-1b0d8c344dc2&deviceToken=AgTGERCBaS3d8n2QWxF9EtwcLktIoygoXpc8Y42ObZWja3RSjN%2bFBeshaY4ASainj3MusBbVopXbUFQrrgXUOSkAbOA7tChNKOFNKQ2gB8sEfCe5Du9BZufW4bAP5312MKRqV8g%3d&deviceType=Pink24
```

I have different versions of my application calling this method. Rather than create a new method, I have used a query string at the end. By parsing the url, I can get the additional parameters I need. ie. deviceToken, deviceId, & deviceType

My request worked fine while the deviceToken parameter was smaller. Now the company providing me with my device token has made an excessively huge one. And now my request returns Bad Request 400.

```
    AgTGERCBaS3d8n2QWxF9EtwcLktIoygoXpc8Y42ObZWja3RSjN%2bFBeshaY4ASainj3MusBbVopXbUFQrrgXUOSkAbOA7tChNKOFNKQ2gB8sEfCe5Du9BZufW4bAP5312MKRqV8g%3d
```

If I remove these characters from the end of my query string, the request goes through successfully. "Q2gB8sEfCe5Du9BZufW4bAP5312MKRqV8g%3d"

I have done some research and discovered that the max for a parameter is 255 characters. My device token is only 140.

To add to my confusion, if I change the order of the deviceId and deviceToken parameters, then I must shorten the deviceId parameter to send successfully. Another point of interest is that if I try to shorten any of the other parameters, then my request still fails. I must always shorten the second parameter.

Has any one else had similar problems and found a solution?

How can I send my looong device token via a query string at the end of a path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after posting this question. Such is often the way.

The device token was getting saved to a field that was NVARCHAR(100). Previously this was enough. The device token can now be at least 140 characters. I changed the field to NVARCHAR(255). The problem is fixed. No more Bad Request 400.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible it's the length of your query string itself, not the parameter.

Try adding

```
<httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="2500" 
maxUrlLength="2500" maxRequestLength="2500" />
```

to your config and see if the error persists